# PHP file upload error Undefined index

Tags: php, html

I have this HTML code:

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="" method="post"  enctype= "multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"><br />
```

This is the PHP code:

```
$target_dir = "/";
    $file = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
    $target_file = $target_dir . $file;
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check['mime'] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
```

And I want upload file but I get this notice message:

> Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload

Comment: Where is form closing tag?

Comment: Form closing tag is there.

Comment: Add a check `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//do something}` add your Php code inside this condition

Comment: Yes, do something.

Comment: Add your code in this condition

Comment: Yes, my code is in this condition.

Comment: Still not working than u need to chk `print_r($_FILES)` chk the correct file Name or share the result

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit'])){} put inside your code it will work

Comment: Problem solved. I was looking for bad php file. Thanks guys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="" method="post"  enctype= "multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"><br />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $target_dir = "/";
    $file = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
    $target_file = $target_dir . $file;
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check['mime'] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
}

?>
```

Comment: I have same code, unfortunately I didn´t paste form closing tag and this condition.